# How to show test class name in visual studio when using inheritance in NUnit?

Tags: c#, inheritance, testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit

Please consider the following test classes:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTestClass
{
    public BaseTestClass(string configFile)
    {
        //Load configurations for test
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Run Test1 based on the current configurations
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        //Run Test2 based on the current configurations
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class FunctionalTests : BaseTestClass
{
    public FunctionalTests() : base("configForFunctionalTests") { }
}

[TestFixture]
public class IntegrationTests : BaseTestClass
{
    public IntegrationTests() : base("configForIntegrationTests") { }
}
```

This is how it shows up in Test Explorer:

[image: Test Explorer]

Is there a way - an attribute maybe - to show the concrete class name rather than the base class name (except for re-sharper which I know can do that)? I tried to use `DescriptionAttribute` but it didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is possible. But you can assign a test category for the class (see http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.6.4) then change that the test shall be grouped in categories in the test results view under "Options -> Group by". But I do not know how this works with subclasses.